# Application Insights query property containing space

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have the following event which I would like to query using Analytics in [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics-reference/)

```
{
    "Description": "Error",
    "EventData": {
       "AccountId": "123",
       "Exception Message": "Data at the root level is invalid.",
       "Error Type": "ExceptionThrown"
     }
}
```

I am able to query the property which does not contain spaces.

```
  Events | where Timestamp > ago(30min)
  | project Data.EventData.AccountId
```

How do I query a property which has spaces. The following query does not work

```
  Events | where Timestamp > ago(30min)
  | project Data.EventData.[Exception Message]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array format accepts quotes.

```
Events | where Timestamp > ago(30min) | project Data.EventData.["Exception Message"]
```

Comment: I tried quotes.... I tried square brackets.... but alas needed both.